# mysql - select count multiple tables, group by week, custom date range

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I have 2 tables and a date range (1 dec 2015 - 10 jan 2016).

First table: USERS

```
id (int)   date (datetime)
 1      3-dec-2015
 2      4-dec-2015
 3      19-dec-2015
 4      20-dec-2015
 5      21-dec-2015
 6      29-dec-2015
 7      30-dec-2015
```

Second table: BIRTHDAYS

```
id (int)   date (datetime)
 1      6-dec-2015
 2      8-dec-2015
 3      9-dec-2015
 4      17-dec-2015
 5      28-dec-2015
```

The result after the query should be the following:

```
[0] 1st week => 2 users, 1 birthday
[1] 2nd week => 0 users, 2 birthday
[2] 3ed week => 1 users, 1 birthday
[3] 4th week => 1 users, 0 birthday
[4] 5th week => 2 users, 1 birthday
[5] 6th week => 0 users, 0 birthday
```

Any ideas how to achive this result or something close? I can use and PHP if needed.

Comment: Your dates are varchar? What is the relation to users and birthday?

Comment: @chris85 There is no relation between the 2 tables, I just need to count the fields and group them by weeek, the date is a date field type.

Comment: Look at the mysql date/time functions needed to parse a character date into a real `datetime` format.

Comment: It's actually a normal date, I just wrote the date in European style for example. I edited my question.

Comment: Use the WEEK function to join the dates in the two tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start off with something like this:

```
select ((week(dateb) - week('2015-12-01')) + 1) as week_number, count(a.dateb) as userdates 
from users as a
where dateb between '2015-12-01' and '2016-01-01'
group by week(dateb)
order by week(dateb);
```

and

```
select ((week(dateb2) - week('2015-12-01')) + 1) as week_number, count(dateb2) as birthdays 
from birthdays
where dateb2 between '2015-12-01' and '2016-01-01'
group by week(dateb2)
order by week(dateb2);
```

Demo, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c83cb/21

from there you can fiddle with the outputting with PHP.

Also note with this approach only rows with populated data are returned. So you should check on the iteration that each row is incremented by 1.

e.g. so for `users` when you got from week 1 to week 3 you should output `week 2  = 0`; or however you want to display it.